# IdentityServer4 Request is too long

Tags: identityserver4

I am getting "bad request - Request is big" on identity server. We asked for multiple API scopes and identity scope - ide-token and token this in result 6 chunks of cookies.

I don't know why I am getting so big cookies and also I have added IProfileService but cursor is not hitting that on Login, why it is not hitted I am not aware as before I remember debugging it.

Just for info - I am using Implicit flow. Currently, no-one is able to login because of this error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to inject the ProfileService in the startup:  .AddProfileService<MyProfileService>();

Comment: Because claims are missing, the login could be redirected back to login, causing a loop.

Comment: Were you able to solve this yourself? Did you change anything in the code that it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Welcome to stack before we can help you we need to see your code.  We need an example of what you are doing that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, Actually I am trying to add some custom claim with User by AddClaim on Login.
This code is executing for each time user is login and adding the claims in the database again and Again, and the login token response is adding all the claims to it, so it fails with Request is too large issue.